# MySQL unifying columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks something like the following:

| id | id_player1 | id_player2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |

I would like to know if there is a way to make it something like:

| id | player_selected | opponent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |

I have got my basic MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `pairings`
WHERE id = $id AND id_player1 = $idPlayer OR id_player2 = $idPlayer
```

I'm not used to make much queries for mysql, and I don't much about them and if this is possible.

Comment: How do we know which player is the selected one - player1 or player2 ?

Comment: By the $idPlayer of the query, maybe this is not reachable to make, Im not used to mysql, so thats why Im asking

Comment: Well, then your query should look like `SELECT id, $idPlayer AS player_selected, CASE WHEN id_player1 = $idPlayer THEN id_player2 ELSE id_player1 END AS opponent FROM pairings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
SELECT id, id_player1 AS player_selected, id_player2 AS opponent
FROM pairings
WHERE id_player1 = $idPlayer
UNION
SELECT id, id_player2, id_player1
FROM pairings
WHERE id_player2 = $idPlayer;
```

This has an advantage that it makes use of indexes on both id_player1 and id_player2.

(Defining column aliases with `AS` is not needed on the second SELECT because the aliases defined in the first SELECT take priority anyway.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for =)

Answer (score 0):

I can to advice next query:

```
select 
    id,
    if (id_player1 = $idPlayer, id_player1, id_player2) as player_selected,
    if (id_player1 <> $idPlayer, id_player1, id_player2) as opponent
from pairings
where id_player1 = $idPlayer or id_player2 = $idPlayer
;
```

This query also can use index based on two fields (id_player1, id_player2)

Here [live SQL](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=47203a57a212e70b0a764fce5f11f441&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)